# HP Elitedesk // USB // File System Not Found (3F0)

Tags: boot, bios, bootable-media, usb-boot, hp

Hope you are doing fine.
I am having this issue where SOMETIMES my EliteDesk 800 G2 Mini does not detect my USB Drive where I have my system installed. This causes me some trouble because I have to reboot several times until it finally detects it and boots or I have to go to the BIOS manually and select the USB drive.

This is a server so, it is convinient to me that if/when there is a power loss, it boots back up on its own (BIOS already setup for that) without any intervention.

Any incredible genius ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Possibly your USB drive takes time to initialize itself, especially if it is a hard drive (i.e. not SSD).  So what you want is to give it more time before the BIOS wants to load the OS from the USB disk.

Looking at [the BIOS manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c05166986.pdf), several things to try to introduce delays in the *Boot Options Menu* (section 5.4, pages 30-31):

1. **Startup Menu Delay**: set to x number of seconds (default is 0)
2. **CD-ROM Boot**: checked (delay while spinning the empty drive)
3. **Boot Order**: Don't put USB in the first place, maybe even enabling Network boot (delay while checking the network)